# Using Azure DevOps REST Api how can I get the build by its build number, except by listing all the builds?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

So I see the Api to get the build by its build Id, but I cannot see one to get it by the build number. Is the only way to list all the builds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an optional parameter on the [builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) API

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.0&buildNumber=0.0.1836.3
```

Comment: Stupid me, I must have missed this argument.

Comment: I think this is because build numbers don't need to be unique.

Comment: They don't have to be, but if you include the build definition in the query string also you will probably get a unique build.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for getting a build according to the build number because theoretically, it could be few builds with the same build number, so if you want to retrieve the build according to the build number you need to get all the builds with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) Rest API and then filter the results.

For example (with PowerShell):

```
# Get the results with Invoke-RestMethod
$builds = Invoke-RestMethod ...
$buildNumber = "10.7"
$myBuild = $builds.value.Where({ $_.buildNumber -eq $buildNumber})
```

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) is the call you are looking for:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.0
```

edit: NVM, I misread the question. there is no way to get the build by its build number.

Comment: I think I have mentioned that I know how to do it by the build Id. I need it by the build number, which is a string, like **0.0.1836.3**

Comment: oh sorry, i misunderstood you, in this case there is no way of doing that.